# routing and navigation in Angular 5

Tags: angular

I am developing a small project in Angular 5, I made the router configuration in the code. On click of the button I want the current view to navigate to he next view. The url changes to the second view url but the view dosen't change. It is not even showing any error. This is what I have done.
The imports in app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './register/register.component';
import { PageNotFondComponent } from './page-not-fond/page-not-
fond.component';


const appRoutes: Routes = [
{ path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
{ path: 'home', component: AppComponent },

{ path: '',   redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: '**', component: PageNotFondComponent }
];

@NgModule({
declarations: [
AppComponent,
LoginComponent,
RegisterComponent,
PageNotFondComponent

],
imports: [
BrowserModule,
FormsModule,
RouterModule.forRoot(
 appRoutes,
 { enableTracing: true } // <-- debugging purposes only

)
],
exports: [ RouterModule ],
providers: [],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.html code:

```
<button class='btn' routerLink="/register" (click)="goToRegisterPage()"> 
Register</button>
```

The app.component.ts code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router,ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
constructor(
private router: Router) { }

goToRegisterPage(){
  this.router.navigate(['register']);
}

}
```

Comment: I almost sure you must import your components too, not only put in "declarations". That's compile?

Comment: What is component.html? Is it supposed to be containg the template of one of the components? Which one? Do you realize your root component has both template and templateUrl, which makes no sense?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following it works for me,

for accessing the following path mentioned

```
{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
```

Go to view of this page and try this

```
<a [routerLink]="['login']">Login</a>
```

and in controller

```
import {Router} from '@angular/router'
```

Comment: No need to bind to `routerLink` if it is a hardcoded string. Use `routerLink="login"` instead.